# How to preset the value of p:fileUpload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, path

I am using `<p:fileUpload>` component. Is it possible to preselect and show the selected file in field before the browse button?

I am using Mojarra 2.0.3, PrimeFaces 2.2 RC2, GlassFish 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if this was possible, this would have been a huge security hole. You would then in theory be able to let the selected file point to `C:/path/to/passwords.txt` and then use JavaScript to submit the form and so silently get a file with sensitive data from the client without its permission.

#### See also:

- [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html/)
- [Send full client side file path to server side using p:fileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698363/send-full-client-side-file-path-to-server-side-using-pfileupload/)

Comment: Hi BalusC, Thank you for the reply. I agree with you. But, Is it possible to show the file name atleast.

Comment: I am requesting you to please look at my question regarding "How to display a confirmation dialog from backing bean" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832222/how-to-display-a-confirmation-dialog-from-backing-bean

Comment: No, this is not possible with HTML. Period. Your best bet is a signed(!) applet.

Comment: Ok.. I am able to convince my customer on this issue. Thank you for the help.