# How to programmatically set the file name and contents in af:inputFile

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, oracle-adf

How to programmatically set values and state of `af:inputFile`, and then move it to 'Update' state from 'Choose File' state?

I need to retain the previous file selection in the UI after the current context has been refreshed (the UploadedFile info is lost), and all I have is a string content of the previous file selection.

Comment: You can't. Not in ADF not in jsf not even in plain html. That would be a security breach. I need to find the duplicafe.

Comment: Although the duplicate is about PrimeFaces, the answer is just as valid for ADF

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preset the value of p:fileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847385/how-to-preset-the-value-of-pfileupload)