# Is there any FacesConfirm class like FacesMessage

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there any `FacesConfirm` like `FacesMessage`?  I need to pass a confirmation dialog instead of message.

```
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("The version " + version + " is already exists.", " The import data will replace the existing data.");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You could however render a `<script>` conditionally.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty bean.confirmMessage}">
    <script>confirm('#{bean.confirmMessage}');</script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Or you could use a 3rd party JSF component library which uses similar mechanism, such as [PrimeFaces'](http://primefaces.org/) [`<p:confirmDialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf).

Comment: Hi BalusC, I am sorry for not describing the problem correctly. Actually, I need to send a confirmation dialog from server side. I have edited my post.

Comment: I have tried the above solution for confirm. But, There is no property "rendered" for <ui:fragment>.

Comment: So you're using Netbeans? Use `<h:panelGroup>` instead.

Comment: Hi BalusC, can you look into my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832222/how-to-display-a-confirmation-dialogprimefaces-from-backing-bean